# Пропуск скрытых объектов схемы данных Access

Tags: c#, sql, .net, access, ado.net

С помощью GetSchema, я получаю все объекты Access.
Как я могу понять является ли таблица скрытой?

Речь идет о пользовательской скрытой таблице.

Comment: О какой версии MS Access идёт речь?

Comment: Файлы имеют формат .mdb т.е 2003, однако для открытия я использую Access 2010+

Comment: Когда-то давно я писал утилиту BatchAccess -- https://rsdn.ru/article/files/progs/BatchAccess.xml -- работает через драйвер Jet, но не изучал как это сочетается с новыми версиями офиса. В любом случае, исходники там есть. По идее, утилитой можно вытащить всю структуру базы в виде SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Системная таблица **MSysObjects** хранит список объектов базы данных MS Access, в т.ч. и таблиц.
В таблице **MSysObjects** есть поле **Flags**. Если таблица имеет атрибут "Скрытая", то значение в поле **Flags**="8".
Соответственно можно в условии запроса указать необходимые критерии поиска: `SELECT [Name] FROM [MSysObjects] WHERE [Type]=1 AND [Flags]=8`.

- [Type]=1 - выборка "родных" таблиц(если прилинкованные, то "6")
- [Flags]=8 - имеют атрибут "скрытая"

Comment: А пользовательская видимая таблица имеет Flags=0 ? Type=1 and Flags=0 я получу все видимые пользовательские таблицы, исключая остальной "мусор"?

Comment: Да, пользовательская видимая таблица обозначается в таблице MSysObjects в поле Flags как =0.
Т.е. запросом: SELECT [Name] FROM MSysObjects WHERE Type=1 AND Flags=0

Вы получите все видимые пользовательские таблицы, исключая остальной "мусор".

Comment: При запросе на выборку ругается, что отсутствуют права...

Answer (score 2):

Опробовал свои старые инструменты. И BatchAccess и BatchAccessGUI работают с .mdb сделанным в Access 2013. И хорошая новость для вас -- через ADOX можно получить свойства таблицы, среди которых есть "Jet OLEDB:Table Hidden In Access".

[image: BatchAccess GUI hidden table]

Для работы с ADOX подключаем "Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.8 for DDL and Security", затем:

```
ADOX.Catalog adoxCatalog = new ADOX.CatalogClass();
adoxCatalog.Create(AConnectionString);
ADOX.Table adoxTable = adoxCatalog.Tables[tablename]
```

Затем в коллекции Properties таблицы найти нужное свойство по имени и взять его значение.

Comment: Эх... Не хотелось использовать COM библиотеки, но видимо другого выбора нет-(